# Do you convert scroll pagination to ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I was wondering if you convert scroll pagination to ajax. Basically I do not want scroll pagination and I want to add a substitute. The scroll pagination query is too large and I want to replace it. Do I convert it to ajax? Here is the code:

```
 feeds.scrollFeedPagination({
 'contentPage': 'index.php',
 'contentData': {
 'last_time' : last_time
 },
 'scrollTarget': feeds, 
 'beforeLoad': function(){
 feeds.parents('#feeds').find('.loading').fadeIn();
 },
 'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){
 $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();
 }
 });
```

If I do not want my scroll pagination do I convert it to ajax? Can somebody post the code?

Comment: Even after reading that text for the third time I still don't get what the heck you want..

Comment: It looks like you're already using AJAX. Presumably whatever you use client-side won't effect your server-side query?

Comment: Yea I tried using ajax and i was not sure if it was the right way to remove the scroll pagination

Comment: What is your definition of "scroll pagination"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check scroll when it touches to bottom then call you'r AJAX function which will will fetch you r records.

```
$(windows).scroll(function(){
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   //call ajax and on it's sucess do whatever you wanted to do
 }
});
```

Let me know if you have any confusion.